# Only match figures with n number of decimal places

Tags: python, regex

```
.500
265.0000
1.000
4.0319
```

How can I just match just .500 and 1.000 or just 265.0000 and 4.0319 on the basis of them having 3 vs 4 digits to the right of the decimal point? Assume I don't know ahead of time how many digits there will be to the left of the decimal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can match against the following regex:

```
^\d*\.\d{3,4}$
```

or for a specific length, just specify one parameter:

```
^\d*\.\d{3}$
```

Lastly, for 3 or more decimal places, do it as:

```
^\d*\.\d{3,}$
```

Comment: Right so I was definitely on the right track - specifying \d{4} returns the figures with 4 decimals exclusive of figures with 3 decimals - great, what I need...but specifying \d{3} returns the figures with 4 decimals in addition to the figures with 3 decimals? Like in the form '.500', '265.000', '1.000', '4.031' Any ideas?

Comment: @user3613243, You need to add the `$` at the end as in my regex

Comment: right of course, I do that and it doesn't return any matches. Anyway, thanks for your help, I should be able to get it figured out from here.